# pass jquery value to php variable

Tags: php, jquery, variables, assign

Am a noob so hope you can help!

I've got the following jquery code:

```
$("#single-home-container").html(post_id);
```

It then displays the value I want within the HTML on the page:

```
<div id="single-home-container"></div>
```

What I would like is to pass the value into a PHP variable to I can use the info in a MySQL query.
How do I do so? It's in WordPress so no separate files

Thanks

Comment: Super vague, what the heck is in post_id? What are you passing over to PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use ajax. Something like this:

JQuery:

```
$('.locationID').click(function(){ 
    var post_id = $(this).attr('rel'),
        $container = $("#single-home-container");
        old_html = $container.html();

    $container.html('loading...');
    $.ajax({
        url : '/path/to/php/file.php',
        data:{"post_id":post_id},
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            $container.html(data.postBody);
        },
        error: function(data){
            // possibly notify the user of the error
            $container.html(old_html);
        }
    });
});
```

That assumes you have a field in your posts table called postBody

PHP

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    // $query_result = do mysql query with $_POST['post_id']
    echo json_encode($query_result);
    exit();
?>
```

That assumes that you want all the fields and you're returning all the fields, including postBody - and of course you have PHP 5.2.6+ or whatever version they added `json_encode()`.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Am not sure how I would use that though. Is there an easier way? Lol

Comment: This is my code
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){      
 $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});     
 $(".locationID").click(function(){         
  var post_id = $(this).attr("rel");           
  $("#container").html("loading...");         
  $("#container").html(post_id);
  return false;    
 });  
}); 
</script>
not sure if that helps?

Comment: Updated, see if that's what you needed.

Comment: With regards to `url : '/path/to/php/file.php', ` as it's a wordpress template and therefore is all in one, do I need this or is there a way to get around it? 

Similarly, to call it on the page, would i then only need
`echo json_encode($query_result); `

Thanks again

Comment: Wordpress is just PHP. You're not locked into creating wordpress templated files, but if that's what you want to do then just wrap your  ajax output in `ob_start()` and `ob_end_flush()` tags.

Comment: Ok I've added that into my main script but i just get null or loading... when I try it.
Will keep trying

Comment: test the ajax page directly with a tool like Poster for [Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chrome-poster/) or [Firefox](http://code.google.com/p/poster-extension/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **jQuery.post()** or **jQuery.ajax()**.

Here some examples:

```
<script>
    $.post("test.php", { "func": "getNameAndTime" },
     function(data){
       console.log(data.name); // John
       console.log(data.time); //  2pm
     }, "json");
</script>

<script>
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){
    $(this).addClass("done");
  }
});
</script>
```